# How to debug appdomain return values in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, appdomain, marshalbyrefobject

my c# programm is using multiple appdomains to load/unload assemblies.
My assemblies in the 2nd appdomain are returning an object which inherits MarshalByRefObject.

My Problem now is that Visual Studio tells me that it can't Show information about it.

> Obtaining the runtime type of a transparent proxy is not supported in this context.

I can see information about this object when I'm in a class of the 2nd appdomain.

My question now: is it somehow possible to tell Visual Studio to Show me information about this object in 1. appdomain?

**Edit:**

I found a solution but this is just a Workaround.
I serialize and deserialize the object from/to json to get a clean copy.

```
var info = Proxy.GetAssemblyInfo(assemblyPath, typeof(IMyAssembly));
#if DEBUG //just to have a debuggable object 
    var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = jsonSerializer.Serialize(info);
    info = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppDomainAssemblyInfo>(json);
#endif

reutrn info;
```

but if there is a nicer solution please let me know :)

**Edit 2:**

Some Code to explain it in detail:

```
var secondAppDomain = CreateAppDomain();

AppDomainLoaderProxy proxy = appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(AppDomainLoaderProxy).Assembly.FullName, typeof(AppDomainLoaderProxy).FullName) as AppDomainLoaderProxy;

var myReturnValue = proxy.getSomeInformation();

//myReturnValue is not debuggable. When I add this to watch-list, VS tells me:
//Obtaining the runtime type of a transparent proxy is not supported in this context.
```

Comment: Pretty unclear why you want to do it this way.  Simply set the breakpoint on the method that returns this object.

Comment: I instanciate an assembly in a 2nd appdomain and call a method there. This method returns an custom object to the 1. AppDomain. When I then try to debug this return-Value (just to see what came back from the second appdomain) I get the above error-message from Visual Studio. I just tried to find out what is inside this object. I can set breakpoints in the 2nd appdomain (that works) but I want to debug the returned values in the 1. Appdomain. Hopefully i explained it understandable

Comment: The debugger is not shy about telling you about this restriction, it is very unclear by what magic you expect it to disappear.  That magic simply does not exist.  Do what works.

Comment: Any "magic" that enables the debugger to show the data in the other AppDomain would work for me.